# memoir error with \stockheight under pdflatex-dev

Tags: pdftex, memoir, latex3

Processing the following source...

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}
Hello.
\end{document}
```

... with the `pdflatex-dev` command  now gives error as shown here:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex-dev)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./memoir-stocksize-error.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> pre-release-2 (develop 2022-10-3 branch)
L3 programming layer <2022-09-28>
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls
Document Class: memoir 2022/07/29 v3.7r configurable book, report, article docu
ment class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)

/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls:409: LaTeX Error
: Command \stockheight already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.409 \newlength{\stockheight}
```

The error does *not* occur when using command`pdflatex`.

The error did not happen with `pdflatex-dev` a few weeks ago. Since the `memoir` package dates to 2022/07/29, it seems the error is caused by pdflatex-dev.

Comment: Yes .. this is a test version of code - I'm not sure what the question here is

Comment: it should work tomorrow again when the firstaid is in texlive.

Comment: The error has now indeed disappeared with pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex-dev) and LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> pre-release-2 (develop 2022-10-5 branch). Thanks for the quick fix!
L3 programming layer <2022-09-28>

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I also get the same mistake today Nov 17 with  pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.10) (preloaded format=pdflatex.fmt) on the same MWE. Any way around that?

Comment: @Xavier_B see https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/960

Comment: Thanks! Works well!