# Compilation errors after updating the memoir class package

Tags: memoir

after updating various packages through the MiKTeX Console today, I am receiving compliation errors in Texmaker which are related to the memoir class package.

A screenshot of those errors can be seen here:
[image]

Is there any quick way to fix this?
If not, could you point me to where I can find and download an older version of the memoir class which has worked? My Google search didn't yield any good results.

Thanks in advance, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: update also LaTeX firstaid.

Comment: duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/660539/memoir-error-with-stockheight-under-pdflatex-dev essentially

Comment: @UlrikeFischer latex-firstaid is up to date as well, sadly it doesn't change anything

Comment: I just tested in my miktex and it works fine. So check for updates in user *and* admin mode.

Comment: Just a reminder. `memoir` is a class not a package.